# jQuery ajax delete script not actually deleting

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, delete-row, sql-delete

I have a little personal webapp that I'm working on. I have a link that, when clicked, is supposed to make an ajax call to a php that is supposed to delete that info from a database. For some unknown reason, it won't actually delete the row from the database. I've tried everything I know, but still nothing. I'm sure it's something incredibly easy... Here are the scripts involved.

Database output:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM bookmark_app";
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
 {
 echo '<div class="box" id="',$row['id'],'"><img src="images/avatar.jpg" width="75" height="75" border="0" class="avatar"/>
     <div class="text"><a href="',$row['url'],'">',$row['title'],'</a><br/>
     </div>
            /*** Click to delete ***/
     <a href="?delete=',$row['id'],'" class="delete">x</a></div>
  <div class="clear"></div>';
        }

    $dbh = null;
```

Ajax script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("a.delete").click(function(){

 var element = $(this);

 var noteid = element.attr("id");

 var info = 'id=' + noteid;

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "includes/delete.php",
    data: info,
    success: function(){
    element.parent().eq(0).fadeOut("slow");
    }
  });
 return false;
 });
});
```

Delete code:

```
include('connect.php');

//delete.php?id=IdOfPost
if($_GET['id']){

$id = $_GET['id'];

//Delete the record of the post
$delete = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `db` WHERE `id` = '$id'");

//Redirect the user
header("Location:xxxx.php");

}
```

Comment: $id = intval($_GET['id']); ever heard of SQL injection?

Comment: SQL what now? Just kidding :) It's still on a localhost in dev stage. I'll dot the i's & cross t's when it goes live.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah just spotted your error, in the href you're generating you're not setting the id attribute. It should be something like:

```
<a href="..." id="'. $row['id'] . '" class="delete">x</a>
```

Of course that's just an immediate example, you **must** escape these kinds of things but this should let you access the item in jQuery.

Comment: Don't forget that 'destructive' requests should be done via POST as otherwise simply browsing to the 'wrong' URL can cause records to be deleted.

Comment: Well, it worked... until I moved it to my web server. Now FireBug is telling me "Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) in xxxx/includes/delete.php  on line 20.
Stupid Media Temple.

Comment: Perhaps http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/4/Why+can%27t+I+connect+to+my+MySQL+database+from+PHP%3F might help you get connected? They have some code samples depending on how you're setup.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to modify your delete script to not just redirect after the DB query. Since it's being called via AJAX, have it at least return a success/error code to the javascript:

```
// can't return $delete unconditionally, since *_query() returns an object
if ($delete) { 
   return(json_encode(array('code' => 1, 'msg' => 'Delete succeeded')));
} else {
   return(json_encode(array('code' => 0, 'msg' => 'Delete failed: ' . mysql_error()));
}
```

It's bad practice to assume a database call succeeded.